# Jquery toggleClass issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

initially hovering works and the "over" class is added on mouseenter and removed on mouseout, but after doing some hovering over paragraphs with class="risk" the toggle class becomes stuck, and mouseover removes it instead of adding the class (opposite of expected functionality)

```
  //changes risk map point color when hovering over
  // risk list item on right hand side
  $("p.risk").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("over");


    var pointId= "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_" + $(this).attr("id");
    var pointArray = $(".riskMapPoint");

    for(i=0; i<pointArray.length; i++){
        if( $(pointArray[i]).attr("id") == pointId )
        {
           $(pointArray[i]).css({'background-color' : '#3D698A'});
           $(pointArray[i]).css({'z-index' : '2'});
        }  
        else
        {
            $(pointArray[i]).css({'background-color' : '#000000'});
            $(pointArray[i]).css({'z-index' : '1'});
        }
     }

    });
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript Error Console in your browser?

Comment: @shawn: you shouldn't roll back the edit you know, it was edited for a reason.

Comment: @shawn: The edit was to fix a format issue with your code to make it more readable.

Comment: yes shawn. Don't you get the rules of this game?

Comment: no Eric, I clearly do not. Haha
I'm new to stack overflow, and wasn't sure what the rollback button would do. Now i know

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply use the hover method?  Set the background/z-index of the associated point on hover and remove it when leaving the element.

```
$('p.risk').hover(
     function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('over');
        $('.riskMapPoint')
                 .find('[id$=' + $this.attr('id') + ']')
                 .css({ 'background-color' : '#3D698A', 'z-index' : 2 } );
     },
     function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('over');
        $('.riskMapPoint')
                 .find('[id$=' + $this.attr('id') + ']')
                 .css({ 'background-color' : '#000000', 'z-index' : 1 } );
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not have two separate functions for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Have `mouseenter` add the class and `mouseleave` remove the class. I think the problem is that if for example the `mouseleave` event is not fired (browser looses focus I think can cause this) then the `mouseenter` function will remove the class instead of adding it.

Comment: Exactly. Separate the two, play with the result and see if it exhibits the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to change css values in code but instead use jquery to addClass and removeClass.  I had a hover problem a couple months ago and applying css classes instead of manually changing values fixed my problem.